# How to disable crash dump for the gen_server

Tags: erlang, gen-server

- There is a gen_server that keeps some sensible information in it's state (password and so on)
- Lagger is enabled,

  So in case of crash gen_server's state is dump to the crash log like:

```
     yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss =ERROR REPORT====
    ** Generic server XXX terminating 
    ** Last message in was ...
    ** When Server state == {state, ...}
    ** Reason for termination ==
```

As a result sensible information is written to the log file.

Are there any way to prevent state of the gen_server to be written into the log files/crash dumps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement [the optional `format_status` callback function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:format_status-2).  That means that whenever the gen_server crashes, you get the chance to format the state data to your liking before it gets logged, for example by removing sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks works good. I ad the following code:  format_status(terminate, [PDict, State]) ->
       State2 = State#state{secret = secret_not_shown},
    [{data,[{"State",State2}]}].

Answer (score 1):

You can add this into your app.config:
`{lager, [{error_logger_redirect, false}]}`
to prevent lager from redirecting error logs. You should also try to catch error (that causes gen_server to crash) and handle it in some graceful way. Our you can keep passwords salted and just let it crash.

Comment: I would assume that {lager,[{error_logger_redirect,false}]} will stop it for the whole application not for the specific gen server. Keep passwords salted would not help as they are needed to work with external servers.

Comment: You can then encrypt them and decrypt on the fly. And by the way erlang has ```try...catch```, so you can always use it to catch error in place.